# Solaris server not accessible after office relocation (including network change)

Tags: solaris, ip-address

We had an office relocation activity as part of which one of our Solaris server was moved to a different location & different network.

We forgot to change the ip of the server before the hardware server was relocated. Now, the server is in a new network and we are not able to login to the server/console using the old ip.

Please note that only the local DT at the site have physical access to the server. Please advise what to do. The server is a critical server and we cannot afford more downtime.

Answer (score 4):

Other than accessing it from the physical console, there's really not much else you can do about it...

If you do have another machine you control that is connected to the same network segment (i.e. to the same switch), you could try to configure a new interface alias on that second machine, set a different IP in the same network as the one the Solaris box was configured for, then see if you can ping the Solaris box from that machine and then finally SSH to the Solaris box so you can reconfigure its IP address (and default gateway, etc.) and reboot it into the correct network.

Be careful, though. If you don't do this correctly, you might end up with even more connection problems or potentially even more unreachable machines in your network.

Next time you're moving server locations, make sure to plan for networking changes accordingly, so you don't end up in the same situation.

Comment: We have some windows machines in that network...will they be of any help ?

Comment: Yes, in theory you can use them to do what I suggested here. But I can't really give you specifics. If you know what these are and do (interface alias, default gateway, etc.) you'll be able to figure out how to connect them and recover that machine. If you don't know what you're doing, you're more likely to end up with more unreachable machines... Do you have an experienced network engineer who can help you? Good luck with your machine recovery!

Comment: For a Windows machine in the same network you might be able to use for instance RDP, VNC or TeamViewer to remotely logon to the windows server, configure an additional IP address and use a SSH client like PuTTY to access the Solaris machine as @filbranden suggested. Another, perhaps easy way is to move the Solaris box back to its previous location, change the network configuration and move the Solaris box to the new location again.